# Object literal braces in html IntelliJ

Tags: html, angular, intellij-idea, webstorm

How can I setup IntelliJ IDEA to format code like

```
hello {{name}}
```

to

```
hello {{ name }}
```

for Angular templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **Auto-insert white space in the interpolation** is enabled in `Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys`, spaces are inserted when completing braces. There is, however, no way to insert them on code reformatting

Comment: thanks a lot, this also required to install AngularJS plugin for me (Intellij IDEA)